# estimating model fit parameters using simulations

Tags: simulation, fitting, uncertainty

I'm trying to fit 2D ellipticals gaussians to an image (with correlated background noise) using prewritten fitting software. I'd like to know about the uncertainty in the fit parameters with this software. To do this I created many simulated images with known "true" source parameters and ran those through the fitting software. Theres 6 fit parameters - gaussian peak, x center position, y center position ,major axis size, minor axis size, and rotation angle - and one calculated parameter of the total integrated power (function of the peak and sizes).

What I want to be able to do is to take my real data and fit it and then use the simulation data to say for a source with fitted parameters x_i the error on the peak is y, error on size is j, etc. But I get confused on how best to do this as the parameters are not independent.

My initial attempt went like: 
1. bin sim data by fitted peak (or Signal to noise ratio)
2. compute ratio of true value to fit value for each parameter
3. compute mean of ratios and standard deviation in each bin
4. fit a function to the SD of the ratios as function of fitted peak
5. take value of fitted peak for real data and use function to calculate what SD should be

But theres two problems with this: 
1. it assumes that the mean of the ratio is 1 (so that the real data has a true value equal to the fit value +/- the computed SD).
2. The SD for the parameters is not just a function of the fitted peaks - i.e. the sources with a low peak and an oversized value for the major axis size will not have the SD as sources with just low peak but size close to true value.

So then I thought to try binning by fitted peak and fitted size - but this parameter space is not very evenly filled out (generally mainly its only sources with low peak values that have large size values). And just not sure best way to interpolate or fit a function at that point.

So I'm wondering if anyone has any thoughts on something like this. Maybe I'm approaching this wrong, and Im sure theres better ways. I'm just getting hung up on the best way to utilize all this simulated data for my real data. Any input would be appreciated.